# "Via Vote" label doesn't show for undeletion in post timeline

Tags: support, timeline, vote-to-undelete

Given that Undelete is a vote type, according to SEDE (and the daily summary), then:

[image]

Why doesn't "via Vote" show in the "Undeleted" box?

Comment: I've only tried this on an answer, so if it applies to questions, please edit the title appropriately.